# CSS Float Form Pattern for WooCommerce Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm attempting to implement the float label pattern (https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/implementing-the-float-label-form-pattern--webdesign-16407) for my WooCommerce forms.

The checkout from is here - https://dev.joshkern.co/checkout/.
You'll first need to add a product/service from here - https://dev.joshkern.co/wordpress-maintenance/. You'll see the form isn't working as it should. What am I missing?

This is my javascript:

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function(){

    // Test for placeholder support
    $.support.placeholder = (function(){
      var i = document.createElement('input');
      return 'placeholder' in i;
    })();

    // Hide labels on page load if placeholders are supported
    if ($.support.placeholder) {
      $('.woocommerce form .form-row').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('js-hide-label');
      });

      $('.woocommerce form .form-row').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function(e){

        // Cache our selectors
        var $this = $(this),
            $parent = $this.parent();

        // Add or remove classes
        if (e.type == 'keyup') {
          if ($this.val() == '') {
            $parent.addClass('js-hide-label');
          }
          else {
            $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label');
          }
        }
        else if (e.type == 'blur') {
          if( $this.val() == '' ) {
            $parent.addClass('js-hide-label');
          }
          else {
            $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label').addClass('js-unhighlight-label');
          }
        }
        else if (e.type == 'focus') {
          if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
            $parent.removeClass('js-unhighlight-label');
          }
        }
      });
    }

  });

})(jQuery);
```